# read markdownfile via jQuery.get()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, get, markdown

I try to read the content of a markdown file via [jQuery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get), so that I can work with the markdown content. But it does not work.

Firebug console report the following:

```
start logging            ondex.html:17:4
end logging              ondex.html:21:4
not wellformed           readme.md:1:2
not wellformed           ondex.html:1:2
```

Somehow the file `readme.md` is read, but there is something not wellformed. I assume, this causes the trouble...

Heres the markdown file. Available on Github as well: [readme.md](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jerik/jerik.github.io/master/readme.md)

```sh
# jerik.github.io
snippset and things I want to capture / document

## todos
- Integrate Navigation dropdown with my pages. The page names should be stated in a tag ( meta-tag, own-tag.. ), so that it can be read by js. 
 - For Layout see: https://bootswatch.com/cerulean/
 - [...]
```

Below the code of the html file where I call jQuery.get() to read the markdown file. Available on Github [ondex.html](https://github.com/jerik/jerik.github.io/blob/master/ondex.html)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Jerik's this and that</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Some stuff that I want to mention" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    // [...]

    console.log( 'start logging' );
    $.get( "readme.md", function( data ) {
        console.log( data ); // this is not called !!
    });
    console.log( 'end logging' );

  </script>
</head>
<body>
<center>das iste in test</center>
<textarea id="ta" theme="cerulean" style="display:none;">
hallo
</textarea>
<script src="v/0.2/strapdown.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**How do I get the content of the markdown file, so that I can work with it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try explicitly setting `dataType` to `"text"`

```
$.get( "readme.md", function( data ) {
        console.log( data ); 
},'text');
```

I m able to get it fine in a plunker demo without doing that but it could be your server setting different headers for the file and jQuery guess of datatype could be handling it differently internally

when in doubt inspect the actual response body in browser dev tools network to see what is actually being received

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/KwfZ6Mz8kS6nSqwRxead?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. Works! I tested it local (no Server). `readme.md` is read now, so I can see it in console.log, but the update of the textarea field (as you have it on your demo) does not work. Perhaps its caused by the local testing...